# How to insert only when condition is true using joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert, sql-update

When doing updates I can check on related columns if the user has permission to update this, like in the following example:

```
UPDATE answer
  JOIN test ON answer.test_id = test.id
SET
  test_answer.answer = 'this is my answer'
WHERE answer.id = 4 AND test.user_id = 8;
```

I want to do something similar when doing inserts, but I have no idea how. I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  answer (id, test_id, answer)
VALUES 
  (null, 10, 'this is my answer')
JOIN 
  test AS test ON test.id = 10
WHERE 
  test.user_id = 8;
```

The idea here is that only the user that owns the test, can add answers to the test.

I could also first fetch the test with id 10, check if the user_id of this test is 8, and then do the insert. But I try to do this in one query.

Comment: there is no such syntax for insert, but you need to let us know, what exactly you are trying to achieve in insert

Comment: @Ravi So does that mean that the only way would be to first fetch the test with id 10, and check the permission and then do the insert?

Comment: your join is useless. you don't even join tables.

Comment: I don't know, what are your trying . which permission, you need to share your design and what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: It seems like you have bad table design, could you share your existing table design ?

Comment: @Ravi The other solution would be to fetch the test with id 10, then check if the user_id is 8, and if so, then do the insert. But I try to do this without having to fetch the test row.

Comment: @Ravi The test table has an id and user_id (and other stuff like, the start_time and end_time of the test etc.). The answer table has an id, test_id and answer. So to understand if the user is allowed to insert into the table, I need to know the user_id value of the associated test row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such syntax for `INSERT` where you can apply `WHERE` clause. If you looking to restrict user to add answer, only if, they have privilege. That's means you need to query your `test` table first see, if user has privilege to this `test_id` as each answer should be associated with `test_id`.

```
SELECT test_id from test where test.id = 10 and test.user_id = 8;
```

If above query returns any rows, then user has privilege to add answer to this particular test. Then, execute your `insert` SQL and you don't need any `WHERE` clause (as you were trying).